# Break out of jQtouch?

Tags: iphone, ajax, jqtouch

I'm trying to give my mobile users the choice to view the full website by loading a different page.

Thing is, jQtouch thoughtfully transforms links into ajax calls, so the user doesn't leave the page at all.

Is there some way to break out of jQt or exclude certain links from loading ajaxically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question.

Inspecting the source code reveals that you can explicitly add an attribute to stop the library trying to "ajaxify" a link:

`target="_blank"` is supported for opening links in new windows

`rel="external"` is supported for the same window.

Comment: rel="external"works fine on Safari on Windows, but not in iPad!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `target="_blank"` to your external links and it should work.

http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=9

Answer (score 0):

If you want jQTouch to ignore the external link, then yes just add `rel="external"` for same-window links or `target="_blank"` for new-window links. However, a common problem is that jQTouch intercepts all AJAX commands (forms, POST commands, etc) and safely submits them itself. This isn't a problem except for when it's expecting some sort of callback, and there isn't one. In a recent project, I wanted to submit a form without a callback. To do this, look in the `jqtouch.js` library (around line 434) and comment out the following line:

```
if (href != '#') {
   $.ajax({
      url: href,
      data: settings.data,
      type: settings.method,
      success: function (data) {
          **// var firstPage = insertPages(data, settings.animation);**
```

This basically just tells jQTouch to submit the AJAX call but do nothing afterwards. It won't change div's, it won't show any callbacks and it won't call any animations. Hope this helps someone.